# ASP.NET MVC Deployment Fail - Azure asking for Nuget Restor

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, deployment, web-deployment

I have successfully deployed an ASP.NET MVC project to Azure. For continuous delivery, this is the error I am getting:

> D:\home\site\repository\MDRIP\MDRIP.csproj(626,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props.
>   Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\MDRIP\MDRIP.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d5ffd0b51ea1fd";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\MDRIP\"

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what build steps are you using? is this via VSTS?

Comment: Please format your question using mark down

Comment: I created a new project and copied all the needed stuff to the new one and problem is solved.